# RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER возвращает Intent = null на версиях API < 21

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, api, null

```java
public void selectAudio() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE,
            getResources().getString(R.string.settings_notification_sound));
    startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_RESULT_SOUND);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.e("GAWK_ERR","onActivityResult. requestCode = " + requestCode + "; data = " + data.toString());
}
```

При вызове кода на версиях API <= 21 в onActivityResult (Intent data = null), на более старших версиях всё отлично работает.
Не могу понять в чем проблема.
Добавлял в манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Не помогло. Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему, не работало из-за того, что в манифесте было указано android:launchMode="singleInstance"